# How to import beautifulsoup in a python script without using import

Tags: python, namecheap

I am trying to run a script on namecheap shared hosting account and they doesn't allow PIP so i cant use it to install BS into the server.

I have a python script [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/zonghua94/APK_download) which i need to run on namecheap server.
And i don't know how to code in python so how do i import BS without using the word import `bs4 from beautifulsoup` which gives the error.

Maybe i can download the whole BS library and upload to to a folder on the server? Something like this?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can append the bs4 path directly to sys.path in your script and then you can use it directly use it without import. Something like this

`import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/bs4/beautifulsoup")
beautifulsoup("something")#now you can use it directly`

Comment: C:\Users\DrDeath\Desktop\APK_download-master>python s.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 116, in <module>
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(targetData, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not define  getting this error..

Comment: download the bs4 lib and append the path to sys.path. `print sys.path` this will give you an idea about where python looks for library files.

Comment: I understand that you are new to python but before asking a question in stackoverflow do enough research. It is because of that you got downvote.